# Query highest supported OpenGL version before context initialization?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glfw

I want to know if there is a way (ideally cross platform, but if not just POSIX compliant or at least in Linux) to query for the highest supported OpenGL version in the current system.

I would like to be able to instantiate GLFW windows to be the highest supported version, rather than blindly trying different versions until one allows for valid context initialization.

EDIT:

Assume I am not creating a context. Imagine I want to replicate what glxinfo does. In other words, I want to be able to query the installed OpenGL version without EVER creating a context.

Comment: `glxinfo` [creates contexts](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos/tree/src/xdemos/glxinfo.c#n432).

Comment: According to [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.4/window_guide.html#window_hints_wnd): *While there is no way to ask the driver for a context of the highest supported version, GLFW will attempt to provide this when you ask for a version 1.0 context, which is the default for these hints.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to create an OpenGL context without querying for a specific version?

When I use native OpenGL functions (glxCreateContext() or wglCreateContext()) to create a new OpenGL context, they always create a context with the highest OpenGL version supported by my graphic card (4.6).

I don't know if GLFW have the same behavior...

ANSWER FOR QUESTION EDIT:
It's impossible to query any of OpenGL informations WHITHOUT creating a context, since you are not able to call any of `glXXX()` functions WHITHOUT creating a context. You can instead create a *dummy* context (which is not shown to the user, but stay somewhere in the memory) to query all OpenGL informations you want, and delete it when you are done (don't worry about it, many many softwares, libraries and also game engines does this, even my [own](https://github.com/AlienEngine))

Comment: "*they always create a context with the highest OpenGL version supported by my graphic card (4.6).*" Sure. If you want the compatibility profile.

Comment: @NicolBolas, then is a possibility to create first a context in compatibility profile to get the highest version, and now create a new context by querying this highest version in core profile.

Comment: @na2axl: Or you could just ask for the version you wrote your code against and move on with your life ;)

Comment: @na2axl which file in your source code should i look for the opengl context creation?

Comment: For sure @Makogan, [here](https://github.com/AlienEngine/AlienEngine.Editor/blob/master/AlienEngine.Editor.UI/Windows/Managers/DummyGLWindow.cs) you will find how I'm creating a dummy GL context for querying informations before delete, hope this will help...

Answer (score 3):

When you ask for version X.Y, you are not asking for version X.Y; you're asking for *at least* version X.Y. Implementations are permitted to give you the highest version which is backwards compatible with X.Y.

So if you ask for 3.3 core profile, you may well get 4.6 core profile. There's no point in the implementation returning a lower version.

So just write your code against a minimum OpenGL version, then ask for that. You'll get whatever the implementation gives you, and you can query what you got later.

---

> Imagine I want to replicate what glxinfo does.

`glxinfo` does what it does by *creating a context*. Just [look at its source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos/tree/src/xdemos/glxinfo.c).

However, the [`GLX_MESA_query_renderer` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/MESA/GLX_MESA_query_renderer.txt) does allow asking about the context that would be created for a particular display/screen/renderer combination. Of course, that only works through MESA; drivers that don't go through MESA's system will not be visible through this.

Comment: What happens if I query for version 3.3 and the highest version is legacy OpenGL?

Comment: @Makogan: Then you don't get a valid context; GLFW yields an error. If you ask for something that cannot be provided, then it isn't provided.